# Android - Compare custom object by multiple fields (different object/primitive types)

Tags: java, android, sorting, comparable

How would you compare a custom object by a String field and an int field?

For example:

```
public class person implements Comparable<Person> {

    String name;
    int age;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NonNull Person another) {
        return name.compareToIgnoreCase(another.name);
    }
}
```

As you can expect, this works well and sorts the person objects in ascending order by name.

My problem:
I also want to sort the list of Person objects by their age as well.

When it is sorted, the List should look like this:

```
name = a, age = 18
name = b, age = 18
name = c, age = 18
name = a, age = 20
name = b, age = 20
name = c, age = 20
...and so on...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, check your primary attributes. If these are equal, check the secondary attributes:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(@NonNull Person another) {
    int result = Integer.compare(age, another.age);
    if (result == 0) {
        result = name.compareToIgnoreCase(another.name);
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

For pre-1.7 Java versions – the manual way:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(@NonNull Person another) {
    if (age == another.age) {
        return name.compareToIgnoreCase(another.name);
    } else if (age < another.age) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. One question though, it says Integer.compare is only API 19+.. is there a solution that is 17+?

Comment: @hitch.united You can simply subtract the ages. 
result = another.age - age

Comment: Subtracting the age's worked perfectly as well. Thank you all.

Comment: You can also use Integer instead of int and then use compareTo() on that Integer variable. i.e.: Integer test = age; test.compareTo(test2);

Answer (score 0):

You could override the compareTo method such that if two objects are equal in name, then you compare with age (or vice versa, depending what you want to sort it by first)